# What is this assembly function prologue / epilogue code doing with rbp / rsp / leave?

Tags: macos, gcc, assembly, stack, x86-64

I am just starting to learn assembly for the mac using the GCC compiler to assemble my code. Unfortunately, there are VERY limited resources for learning how to do this if you are a beginner. I finally managed to find some simple sample code that I could start to rap my head around, and I got it to assemble and run correctly. Here is the code:

```
.text                                           # start of code indicator.
.globl _main                                    # make the main function visible to the outside.
_main:                                          # actually label this spot as the start of our main function.
    push    %rbp                            # save the base pointer to the stack.
    mov     %rsp, %rbp                      # put the previous stack pointer into the base pointer.
    subl    $8, %esp                        # Balance the stack onto a 16-byte boundary.
    movl    $0, %eax                        # Stuff 0 into EAX, which is where result values go.
    leave                                   # leave cleans up base and stack pointers again.
    ret
```

The comments explain some things in the code (I kind of understand what lines 2 - 5 do), but I dont understand what most of this means. I do understand the basics of what registers are and what each register here (`rbp`, `rsp`, `esp` and `eax`) is used for and how big they are, I also understand (generally) what the stack is, but this is still going over my head. Can anyone tell me exactly what this is doing? Also, could anyone point me in the direction of a good tutorial for beginners?

Comment: If you dont know assembly, x86 is the worst one to learn first.  And having the hardware is the worst excuse I have heard for learning x86 first (you dont want to learn on hardware the first time).

Comment: If you want to learn by doing something useful, and you're profiling something on x86, you might as well learn x86 asm first.  Modern user-space x86 is not bad.  Yes it's complex if you're trying to write an OS, rather than look at compiler output for normal programs, but don't do that first.  There are lots of good links to reference and learning manuals in [the x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Stack is a data structure that follows [LIFO principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIFO_(computing)). Whereas stacks in everyday life (outside computers, I mean) grow upward, stacks in x86 and x86-64 processors grow downward. See [Wikibooks article on x86 stack](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/The_Stack) (but please take into account that the code examples are 32-bit x86 code in Intel syntax, and your code is 64-bit x86-64 code in AT&T syntax).

So, what your code does (my explanations here are with Intel syntax):

```
push %rbp
```

Pushes `rbp` to stack, practically subtracting 8 from `rsp` (because the size of `rbp` is 8 bytes) and then stores `rbp` to `[ss:rsp]`.

So, in Intel syntax `push rbp` practically does this:

```
sub rsp, 8
mov [ss:rsp], rbp
```

Then:

```
mov     %rsp, %rbp
```

This is obvious. Just store the value of `rsp` into `rbp`.

```
subl    $8, %esp
```

Subtract 8 from `esp` and store it into `esp`. Actually this is a bug in your code, even if it causes no problems here. Any instruction with a 32-bit register (`eax`, `ebx`, `ecx`, `edx`, `ebp`, `esp`, `esi` or `edi`) as destination in x86-64 sets the topmost 32 bits of the corresponding 64-bit register (`rax`, `rbx`, `rcx`, `rdx`, `rbp`, `rsp`, `rsi` or `rdi`) to zero, causing the stack pointer to point somewhere below the 4 GiB limit, effectively doing this (in Intel syntax):

```
sub rsp,8
and rsp,0x00000000ffffffff
```

**Edit:** added consequences of `sub esp,8` below.

However, this causes no problems on a computer with less than 4 GiB of memory. On computers with more than 4 GiB memory, it may result in a segmentation fault. `leave` further below in your code returns a sane value to `rsp`. Generally in x86-64 code you don't need `esp` never (excluding possibly some optimizations or tweaks). To fix this bug:

```
subq    $8, %rsp
```

The instructions so far are the standard entry sequence (replace `$8` according to the stack usage). [Wikibooks has a useful article on x86 functions and stack frames](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Functions_and_Stack_Frames) (but note again that it uses 32-bit x86 assembly with Intel syntax, not 64-bit x86-64 assembly with AT&T syntax).

Then:

```
movl    $0, %eax
```

This is obvious. Store 0 into `eax`. This has nothing to do with the stack.

```
leave
```

This is equivalent to `mov rsp, rbp` followed by `pop rbp`.

```
ret
```

And this, finally, sets `rip` to the value stored at `[ss:rsp]`, effective returning the code pointer back to where this procedure was called, and adds 8 to `rsp`.